# Ubuntu 20.04 secondary display not getting past splash screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, lightdm, 20.04, hdmi

I am on gnome, with the lightdm display manager, with an Nvidia graphics card, the latest 440 drivers from the PPA is installed, and the HDMI output is detected via xrandr as shown below:

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  59.96    59.93
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      59.90    59.82
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.32
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Yet when I try to use the secondary monitor the screen just shows the splash screen loading forever. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What happens if you use gdm3?

Comment: My primary display is not detected for some reason, my guess is a bad config file but I don't know

Comment: Your question indicates a problem with the **secondary** display. Which is it?

Comment: My secondary display, I'm trying to load my second display on lightdm

Comment: What DM are you using for your "primary/first" display? What did you change/modify to use lightdm? Did you try using gdm3 as per my first comment? Are you using Wayland?

Comment: Lightdm like I said in the question

Comment: You're not listening. gdm3 is the default DM on 20.04. You're trying to use LightDM. I'll ask again... what happens if you use gdm3? Are you using Wayland?

Comment: I'm using Wayland and when I use gdm3 I get no output on my laptop primary display

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu 20.04, you booted from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, yes? That was using gdm3 and X11/xorg, not Wayland. And that worked, yes? You may have a BIOS issue. In `terminal` type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` then go to the manufacturer's web site and see if there's a newer BIOS. Report back.

Comment: Also, at the login screen, try using "Ubuntu", not "Ubuntu on Wayland", and see if anything changes.

Comment: It is the latest version of my bios

Comment: Which Nvidia adapter? Did you try the non-Wayland login yet?

Comment: My Nvidia adapter is the ppa version 440

Comment: That's the driver. What **adapter** is in your laptop?

Comment: Nvidia Gdx 1050 ti

Comment: Let me go look at something. BRB. In the mean time, please try the non-Wayland login.

Comment: Is your Nvidia driver 440.82?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest 440 version

Comment: The .82 version, or something older?

Comment: Also I tried no Wayland with the same result

Comment: How do I tell the version?

Comment: `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`

Comment: Yes I have the . 82 version installee

Comment: Just curious... what brand/model laptop?

Comment: Hp omen 15 ce-0xx

Comment: Do you know how to boot using `nomodeset` from the GRUB menu?

Comment: Yes, I'll give it a shot

Comment: It's saying a start job is running for a long time

Comment: You changed "quiet splash" to "quiet splash nomodeset", yes?

Comment: Yes, I changed quiet splash to quiet splash nomodeset

Comment: Did this monitor setup **ever** work on **this** laptop? If you have Windows, does it work there?

Comment: It used to work just yesterday, when I set it up last. I wake up today and nothing

Comment: Try the nomodeset thing one more time. Report back.

Comment: It just does the same thing again

Comment: Just to confirm... you have a HP laptop display, and an external HDMI display, yes? And which doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, the set up is a HP laptop and a TV set for secondary display,

Comment: Just to confirm... And which doesn't work?

Comment: The TV set is just showing my Ubuntu splash screen, like the one you see at boot up time, forever

Comment: In the setup of the TV, can you, or did you, change the default resolution? What resolution is it when it's showing the boot splash?

Comment: The resolution is 1080 p the default

Comment: Try 1080i, or 720.

Comment: That's where my problem is, Ubuntu is not picking up my HDMI output to screen, it detects audio but not video on the TV, as my xrandr shows in the question

Comment: Do you have another HDMI cable to try?

Comment: I don't think it's the cable or the Ubuntu splash screen would not show up on the tv

Comment: But no I don't have one else

Comment: The problem is not that uncommon... where a TV monitor doesn't correctly give up its characteristics to the host. Question... you probably have multiple HDMI ports on the TV. Are any of them labelled differently than the others... like for instance, does one say MHT, or PC? Try a different port.

Comment: Same result happened just the splash screen

Comment: I wish you had another HDMI cable to try. I'm out of ideas for now. Sorry.

Comment: Please keep me posted if you find a solution.

Comment: @ShadowLynch the way to respond here is to edit the answers to questions into your question.  Trying to follow a long comment thread is difficult!  Please can you do so - you can then remove your comments. thx